# Laravel 8 query working in development but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: php, database, heroku, laravel-8, production

I have an autocomplete search controller in Laravel that makes an ajax call to a search controller:

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{ 
$data = Subject::where('title', 'LIKE', $request->subject.'%')->take(8)->get();
    $output = '<ul class="origin-top-right right-0 mt-2 w-56 shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5" style="display:block; position:relative; overflow-y: scroll;">';
    if (count($data)>0) {
        foreach ($data as $row){
            $output .= '<li><button style="text-align: left;" class="w-full block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">'.$row->title.'</button></li>';
        }
    }
    else {
        $output .= '<li><button style="text-align: left;" class="w-full block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">'.'No results'.'</button></li>';
    }
    
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}
```

The dev database is mysql and the prod is pgsql and tracing the code shows that the line         **`$data = Subject::where('title', 'LIKE', $request->subject.'%')->take(8)->get();`** is returning empty in production but is filled correctly in development and I have checked that my prod database is seeded correctly and the Subject model works ok, please help, thank you!

Comment: Can you share error or more details to give a proper solution .

Comment: Sure thank you, I recreated the problem with a simple Country Autocomplete.  Here is the repo: https://github.com/vsahinid/laravel-autocomplete and here is the heroku prod server: https://autocomplete-laravel-prod.herokuapp.com/.  If you clone the app and run it on your local it works but when trying to choose a country from the autocomplete it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

i have update your controller file replace this .

Issue is that in localhost lower case or upper case its works fine when in live server upper case and lower case both are different values so that is problem in now i have solve your solution .

**CountryController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Country;
use DB;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
    public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    { 
        // return Country::all();
      if($request->ajax()) {
        //$data = Country::where('name', 'LIKE', $request->country.'%')->take(10)->get();
        $data = Country::where(DB::raw('LOWER(name)'), 'like',  strtolower($request->country) . '%')->limit(10)->get();
    //dd($data->toArray());
        $output = '<ul class="origin-top-right right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5" style="display:block; position:relative; overflow-y: scroll;">';
    if (count($data)>0) {
        foreach ($data as $row){
            $output .= '<li><button style="text-align: left;" class="w-full block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">'.$row->name.'</button></li>';
        }
    }
    else {
        $output .= '<li><button style="text-align: left;" class="w-full block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">'.'No results'.'</button></li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
  }
}

public function update_countries(Request $request){
    $countries = Country::all();
    dd($request);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you tremendously this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: i have tested on live server also now working enjoy my coding .